# Penalizing common words in LDA analysis

Tags: machine-learning, latent-variable

I have a corpus I want to perform an LDA on, however it has very few total words and some words occur extremely often.  I want to penalize these words.  A [tfidf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) at first seemed intuitive (and I have found literature where this has been used on LSA's).  However and LDA expects a bag of words (and those words occur in integers...doesn't really make sense for the word "fun" to occur 2.5 times in a document).

Are there any good pre/post processing techniques to get similar effects as a tfidf while working on an LDA?

Comment: What is your aim in using latent Dirichlet allocation? Specifically, are you using it solely as an unsupervised technique to explore the corpus, or using the document distributions as features in a supervised learning model?

Comment: I have a large corpus that I want to train on and new unseen documents that I want to classify into topics using the result of the LDA's training

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N10-1070) presents term weighting schemes for LDA, and reports improved precision on an example retrieval task. I've not verified these results, and it doesn't mention an available software implementation, but this may be a good place to start. In brief, it suggests using term *weight* rather than raw count, and presents a few different weighting schemes (logarithmic and point-wise mutual information).

If you'd like to go further, you may wish to peruse the [subsequent papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=11695044608013337802&as_sdt=20005&sciodt=0,9&hl=en) citing this one.